# How to send text email from Inbox by Gmail

Tags: inbox-by-gmail

As in per title, is there a way to optionally send an email in plain text instead of HTML?

Comment: **Inbox by Gmail** was retired in April, 2019 and is no longer available.

Comment: @ale did you just really comment a question posted on 2016 which is obviously not relevant anymore and nobody is going to look at this anyway?

Comment: When you choose the "Off Topic - Other" close reason you're required to put in a comment.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The only way I found is to **not** use Inbox for plain text email. For such emails (the git mailing list accepts only plain text emails, for example), I need to switch to using Gmail only to compose plain text emails.

Gmail has this "feature"..

- Click Compose
- Click the "More Options" 3-dot icon
- Select "Plain text mode"

[image]

Comment: Note that plain text mode is [not well supported in Gmail either](https://mathiasbynens.be/notes/gmail-plain-text).

Answer (score 3):

This is not possible at the moment. The only (remote) option you have is to compose your email and then remove the formatting (available only in the desktop version). I know it’s not even close to being the same, but there is no other option for the time being.